# MySQL Percrona 8.0 became suddenly slow until restart mysql

Tags: mysql, percona, performance, slow-log

My website today suddenly became slow and all requests were taking about 2 seconds to complete. 
Usually it takes like 0.2 second I checked available space on disk and I have a lot.

Memory and CPU usage are usual nothing weird, error log is empty.

Tried to login to MySQL using the following command:

`mysql -u root -p`

it says "Enter Password" then after I enter the password it takes forever.

then I decided to restart mysql `sudo service mysql restart` and it removed the slowness and fixed the problem which I hate, because I don't know what was the problem and how to avoid that in the future or fix.

What do I need to look at in this case, how to get more information about that issue?

Comment: You want to monitor performance data about your database, generally gather as much information as possible, before you take the step of restarting. Most useful information is gone then. A good start is probably percona's monitoring, which you can easily run in a docker container: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-and-management/index.html

Comment: slow query log. Will find you some queries. `EXPLAIN {query}`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` from queries. Edit question with this information. Also query profile.

Comment: @tombom Thanks I will take a look on that, I had to restart visitors were complaining of that issue.

Comment: @danblack mysql isn't responsive at all, which prevented me from doing such queries

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.